# ESRI's WmsLayer failure

Tags: wms, silverlight, arcgis-silverlight-api

I've been using the WmsLayer for my WMS Service needs, rather than my old way of doing things by sussing out a GetMap URL and posting that image to a GraphicsLayer. It's been working well but I seem to have found a service that breaks it.

Here is the getCapabilities URL I'm using:

```
http://ags.pdc.org/arcgis/services/global/pdc_active_hazards/MapServer/WMSServer?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

I'm able to to get the Name of the layers available (they're using simple numbers to ID them). I provide the WmsLayer the  getCapabilitiesURL, the layer ID number & a Proxy Url based upon the proxy handler from the documentation here at ESRI. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be enough. When debugging, I crash to an unhandled exception as soon as I add it to my map control.

```
Category: ManagedRuntimeError
Message: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
```

Using Firebug to look at my hosted application, it reports this error:

```
Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options)
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.WmsLayer.client_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)
```

The XML returned by the GetCapabilities call seems sound to me - at least it appears like all of the other WMS services I've been communicating with - so I'm not sure what parsing errors it is running into. Any ideas? I can provide further info if there is something I haven't thought to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I asked over on the ESRI forums and discovered an interesting... quirk?

I was having an issue adding my WmsLayer dynamically in code. What I have misunderstood, it seems, is that the URL property simply needs the URL to the WMS service endpoint.

So:

```
wLayer.Url = "http://ags.pdc.org/arcgis/services/global/pdc_active_hazards/MapServer/WMSServer";
```

Rather than:

```
wLayer.Url = "http://ags.pdc.org/arcgis/services/global/pdc_active_hazards/MapServer/WMSServer?service=wms&request=getcapabilities";
```

I've now been going through other WMS servers I've been hitting because I feel certain that I've used URLs with parameters specified and it displayed the overlays just fine. Internally I presume the WmsLayer is sussing out the appropriate getCapabilities and getMap URL strings itself and I was throwing it off by setting those parameters in the URL property.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this service in our Silverlight viewer and got this error:

```
 CRITICAL: Unhandled exception occured: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

   Details:
      at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
      at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.WmsLayer.ParseCapabilities(XDocument xDoc)
      at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.WmsLayer.client_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
      at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
      at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)
```

By looking at [the Source for WmsLayer.ParseCapabilities](https://esrisilverlight.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Source/Silverlight/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources/Wms/Wms.cs), I see that the API will parse the capabilities differently if it determines that this service is not a WMS 1.3.0 service.  I presume that your viewer is doing this - try adding `VERSION=1.3.0` to your WMS URL.

Comment: Okay, so I tried adding this parameter and with no luck. I also tried to set the version property of the WmsLayer to 1.3.0 and SkipCapabilities to true.